# Excel nested IF(INDEX(IFERROR(MATCH)

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Morning all my first post here, need some advice on a complex formula.  I do not code - no VBA, no macros.  Working in a massive hospital company and focused on process improvement.  as such lots of compliance concerns and will have to dummy up data if example sheets are needed.

The short version - i have a weekly project that runs on a template I built.  It works well currently.  I have a monthly report that this weekly project compares to and pulls data from.  The monthly report is incredibly heavy - not less than 1000 lines of data, and I index one of two data points from it, based on a match of one of eight columns.   I've gotten an index/iferror/match formula working to capture half of the data.  However i am stumbling on what should in theor be the easiest part.

The desired outcome is on the weekly tab in column D - the formula needs to evaluate first whether the value in WEEKLY column C "type" is "I" or "O".  Then based on that result, the index/iferror/match which change the index from MONTHLY column U to MONTHLY column V.

Currently the formula i have works as an index on MONTHLY column U, and properly evaluates whether WEEKLY A, or B, or C, or D, or E or F or G or H is matched.  When I wrap the whole thing in an "IF([@[Type]]=I,INDEX...) then it immediately errors.    Any advice is appreciated.  Screenshot of "WEEKLY" and "MONTHLY" below with a copy of the current half-effective formula in the weekly column D slot for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkhsL.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question right now might need some improvement. Could you please provide a minified with code examples of the problem you are facing, what you have tried, and the desired output. Screenshots of text are quite difficult to work with. If you can produce a specific, testable question it will be easier for folks to help you out.

Comment: Thanks Rob - attempting to attach a dummy version of the sheet now...

Comment: is there a way to attach a spreadsheet?  i can't find anything except an "add hyperlink" option or a photo option...

Comment: In the sample data you have provided, there is no match for 1541_1451, so your formula should return #N/A. Did you mean 1541_451? Or have I not spotted something?

Comment: Gravitate - the data sample in that screenshot is extremely limited.  in actuality there is a 1541_1451.  there are about 8000 points spread across columns A-H in the real world, not included in that pic